# Good Solution for Jquery show hide Div section

Tags: jquery, html, css, single-page-application, show

I am using `Jquery` to show hide section of div blocks based on User interaction on page.

Using other `framework` is not an option, page interaction is mostly like Single page `behavior`.

Currently my JS Code is Full of all these code,
I am looking for possible code `optimization` or any other approach to handle this type of `scenario`.
Thanks in advance

I have used `toggleClass` of `Jquery`. :visible of `Jquery` Features.

```
   // New section
    $(document).on('click', '.sone_button_1', function () {
        $('.div_5').removeClass('hidden');
        $('.div_6').removeClass('hidden');
        $('.div_2').addClass('hidden');
        $('.div_1').addClass('hidden');
        $('.div_4').addClass('hidden');
    });
    // new section
    $(document).on('click', '.some_list_2', function () {
        $('.div_3').removeClass('hidden');
        $('.div_2').removeClass('hidden');
        $('.div_5').addClass('hidden');
    });

    // new section
    $(document).on('click', '.some_button_2', function () {
        $('.div_1').removeClass('hidden');
        $('.div_3').addClass('hidden');
        $('.div_4').addClass('hidden');
        $('.div_5').addClass('hidden');
    });
  ...
```

It working as per Expected, But need more to make it efficient and possible interactions.

Comment: You could most likely simplify this with common classes and DOM traversal. If you could post your HTML we could confirm this and offer you some solutions

Comment: You could use active and inactive classes to div [Demo link](https://jsfiddle.net/karthickj25/31urtqwp/) each pagination achieve the same by hiding and showing the div

Comment: When you click a button you could assign a classname to the body element and add some css rules that hide your divs depending on that class.

Comment: One way to make it more efficient is to not do event delegation from the document. You should use the closest static parent. Also to make your code less repeating you could do `$('.div_5, .div_6').removeClass('hidden');`

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `.hide()` and `.show()` in JQuery and a class for the div's that belong together.

It looks simple and you don't have to use *CSS* Code.

```js
/* 
 * All interaction happen in same PAGE, 
 */
// New section
$(document).on('click', '.some_button_1', function() {
  $('.hide-first').hide();
  $('.hide-second').show();
});

// new section
$(document).on('click', '.some_button_2', function() {
  $('.hide-first').show();
  $('.hide-second').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hide-first">Div-1.1</div>
<div class="hide-first">Div-1.2</div>
<div class="hide-first">Div-1.3</div>

<div class="hide-second">Div-2.1</div>
<div class="hide-second">Div-2.2</div>
<div class="hide-second">Div-2.3</div>

<button class="some_button_1">Hide First Show Second</button>

<button class="some_button_2">Show First Hide Second</button>
```

Comment: I just made an example on how it works. It can be used for `some_list_2` as well. 
@Znaneswar I also had no html code so I made it on my own.

Answer (score 0):

Probably just a matter of organizing what happens when each button/list is clicked? This saves you from writing repeated code and makes it more flexible:

```js
let interact_mapping = {
    '.some_button_1': [
        ['.div_5', true],
        ['.div_6', true],
        ['.div_2', false],
        ['.div_1', false],
        ['.div_4', false],
    ],
    '.some_list_2': [
        ['.div_3', true],
        ['.div_2', true],
        ['.div_5', false],
    ],
    '.some_button_2': [
        ['.div_1', true],
        ['.div_3', false],
        ['.div_4', false],
        ['.div_5', false],
    ],
};

const $document = $(document);

Object.keys(interact_mapping).forEach(function(interact_selector) {
    let interact_targets = interact_mapping[interact_selector];
  
    $document.on('click', interact_selector, function() {
        for (let target_index = 0; target_index < interact_targets.length; target_index++) {
            let target = interact_targets[target_index];
            
            if (target[1]) {
                $(target[0]).removeClass('hidden');
            } else {
                $(target[0]).addClass('hidden')
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button class="some_button_1">
    some button 1
  </button>
  <button class="some_list_2">
    some list 2
  </button>
  <button class="some_button_2">
    some button 2
  </button>
</div>
<div class="div_1">
  div 1
</div>
<div class="div_2">
  div 2
</div>
<div class="div_3">
  div 3
</div>
<div class="div_4">
  div 4
</div>
<div class="div_5">
  div 5
</div>
<div class="div_6">
  div 6
</div>
```